# IDE Error: Cannot paste TToolButton in the designer

Tags: delphi, ide, clipboard, delphi-10.1-berlin

In the Delphi 10.1 IDE create a VCL Application. Then insert a `TToolBar` on the Form. Then create a new `TToolButton` on the toolbar. Then COPY the button to the clipboard. Then select the toolbar. Then try to PASTE the button from the clipboard to the toolbar. An error message is displayed:

[image]

This is strange, as I assume that any control which has been copied from a container could be pasted back to the same container.

Is this a bug and can this error be avoided?

Comment: Indeed a bug. You should be able to do that from the UX point of view.

Comment: How did you manage to copy to the clipboard? I can't. CTRL+C does nothing, Copy and Cut are greyed out. I am using 10.1

Comment: @Dsm I get that problem all the time for various controls, but usually in the Firemonkey form designer.

Comment: As a workaround, you might be able to copy&paste the relevant fragment in text view (Alt-F12).

Comment: @JerryDodge maybe so, but it seems very consistent (maybe it is with you too) so OP must be doing something different to me, or his installation is somehow different to mine.

Comment: @Dsm Right-click the button -> Edit -> Copy. When pasting with the context menu the Paste item sometimes is disabled. This also seems to be a bug in the IDE functionality. Posting these bugs at the Quality Control website seems to have no effect: Even bugs reported since many years are not fixed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that method. It didn't work. So I agree - several bugs. I tried copying the text fragment from the text view and then pasted that and was able to get your error message that way.